# Is there a way to assign meetings to the rooms according to minimum capacity of room in OptaPlanner Meeting Scheduling example?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm looking at OptaPlanner meeting scheduling example. There are rooms and people. I've defined minimum and maximum capacity for every room then I'm trying to implement some rules. One rule is don't exceed the maximum capacity and I've implemented this rule like this:

```
rule "Max Quota"
    when
    $ma : MeetingAssignment( room != null,$city: city, $room:room, $roomCapacity : roomCapacity)
    accumulate(
        $m2 : MeetingAssignment(room != null,city==$city, calculateOverlap($ma) > 0, room.getRoomName() == $room.getRoomName());
        $total : count($m2);
        $total > $roomCapacity
    )
    then
        scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, -50000000);
end
```

It's working. Now I want to implement minimum capacity. For example, there are four rooms and their maximum capacity is 60 and minimum capacity is 20 (or can be different) for every room. After assignment one room filled with 50 person, second 40, third 60 and the last one is just 10 person. Last room is under 20. I don't want to assign fairly like 40, 40, 40, 40. It is enough that the last room is more than 20. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It's better to penalize the a multiplication of the number of missing capacity than just the fixed value of `-50000000`. So make it something like `-50000000 * ($total - $capacity)`. See *Score Trap* in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `roomCapacity` to `roomMaximumCapacity`. Then add `roomMinimumCapacity`. Then add a constraint rule to deal with that too.